# Have $134 billion in U.S bonds been faked or secretly sold or "lost" by a superpower?

Tags: economics

I just found [this long post](http://www.divinecosmos.com/start-here/davids-blog/995-lawsuit-end-tyranny) (via [Bitcoin Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/oghok/85_percent_of_gold_in_the_world_is_hidden_off_the/), that might contain a TL;DR).

The post is extremely long and rife with conspiracy theories. I'll try to summarize the main claim:

**134 billion dollar** worth of U.S treasury bonds were recently (2009) confiscated on the Italian border. Only four countries (China, UK, Japan, Russia) even have that kind of money. This represents either a massive, ultra high quality forgery (such that only a country is capable of), or a huge secret dumping of U.S bonds **by a major super power**.

Comment: "As of November 28, 2011, media outlets announced that we could be as little as ten days away from a complete collapse of the Euro" Well, "six-to-eight weeks" have passed since then, and no progress...

Comment: Perhaps not authoritative in conspiracy cases, but [Wikipedia has some background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasso_financial_smuggling_case).

Comment: So if someone were to post proof here that the US Government had covered up a mass sale of bonds would we not expect the US Government to punish SE the way it punished Wiki-leaks?

Comment: @Chad - not if they just link to things that are already public. Wiki-leaks took confidential documents and published them ... I don't think this will happen on SE.

Comment: I am voting to close as not constructive.  For situations like these the burden of proof is on the claimant to prove not the skeptic to disprove.

Comment: @Chad - the claimant claims the proofs are in his very long post. I tried reading it, but couldn't get past the first couple of pages.